Imagesharp throwing System.MissingMethodException
I was using *System.drawing * library to create image which was working fine on windows but is not supported on Linux. As a result I needed to migrate to Imagesharp.
Here is the piece of code I am using:
Stream imageStream= GetImage(imageUrl);

Image image= Image.Load(imageStream);
image.Mutate(img=>img.Resize(width,height));
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
image.SaveAsPng(ms);
return XImage.FromStream(()=>new MemoryStream(ms.ToArray()); 

In the last line of this code error is thrown  System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image`1<!!0> SixLabors.ImageSharp.Image.Load(System.IO.Stream, SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.IImageFormat ByRef)
I am unable to figure out why this particular method is invoked implicitly.
Can anyone help me to figure out why this is happening and how to fix this.
Pdfsharpcore version: 1.3.63
Imagesharp version: 3.14
.Net version:6.0

You are getting this issue due to the fact that PdfSharpCore targets a really old version of ImageSharp, its targeting v1.0.4 and there have been numerous breaking changes between then an now.
There are 2 options really, 1. you will need to push the maintainer of PdfSharpCore to update to a more recent version of the ImageSharp or 2. downgrade your own dependency version of ImageSharp to the version it targets.
Option 2 of downgrading ImageSharp has some inherent risks however due to the fact that v1 is completely out of support and is no longer receiving updates even security related ones (and there have been a few no has security fixes pushed recently that are likely to be present in that outdated version). Ultimately its your choice and decision on what risks you are comfortable with  taking.

I am using the most recent version for pdfsharpcore and imagesharp. However still it throws the error.

The most recent version of PdfSharpCore is not compatible with the most recent version of ImageSharp hence push the maintainers to update the package itself or downgrade your version of ImageSharp (with all the risks as outlined above)

@tocsoft shouldn't be downvoted. this is the answer. source: see their github issues
